# JSF Exception Tags not rendered on page

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I created a sample JSF project and trying to run in tomcat 6 but getting errors when the page is showing up. I am newbie to JSF. I also tried changing the file name to html and welcome list to show login.html but then JSF tags are not rendered on my page

login.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title> Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name</td>
                <td><h:inputText value="#{user.name}"></h:inputText></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml is as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>ivr</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

And also faces-config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
version="1.2">
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>user</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.ivr.User</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<application>
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

Exception:

```
Class com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler is no javax.faces.application.ViewHandler
Caused by:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Class com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler is no javax.faces.application.ViewHandler
```

If i rename the **login.xhtml** to **login.html** and also change the welcome file list to login.html the exception goes away but I can't see my JSF tags rendered on my page.

Comment: *If i rename the login.xhtml to login.html and also change the welcome file list to login.html the exception goes away but I can't see my JSF tags rendered on my page* that's because the view is never handled by Faces Servlet. Are you using Mojarra or MyFaces as JSF implementation?

Comment: @Luiggi: The `<listener>` entry and the fact that the OP managed to startup the webapp as far as the `faces-config.xml` is successfully been parsed suggests MyFaces.

Answer (score 3):

> *Class com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler is no javax.faces.application.ViewHandler*

This suggests that you're using JSF 2.x which has Facelets bundled, but are yet still attempting to manually bundle/register Facelets 1.x  which is specifically designed for JSF 1.x.

Get rid of all Facelets 1.x artifacts, including the `jsf-facelets.jar`, the `<view-handler>`,  all the `<context-param>` entries and also the `<listener>`. You do not need them when using JSF 2.x. You have perhaps added them while carelessly reading a JSF 1.x book/tutorial/resource instead of a JSF 2.x targeted one.

Then, make sure that your physical Facelet file has the `.xhtml` extension and that the welcome file also points to exactly that extension. Last but not least, fix your `faces-config.xml` root declaration to comply JSF 2.0.

Before continuing learning JSF, I strongly recommend to review your books/tutorials/resources if they are really JSF 2.x targeted. [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) is a good starting point.

Comment: Just to note, the *faces-config.xml* file points to JSF 1.2 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update. i am using jsf 1.2(Apache MyFaces JSF Core 1.2 API 1.2.9) jar in my library path